# Is NEST 5.x and Elasticsearch.Net 5.x compatible with Elasticsearch 2.4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have project referenced to NEST 5.x and Elasticseacrh.Net 5.x. And Elasticsearch 2.4.0. Are they compatible?

Comment: No, they are not: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix

Comment: @RussCam Thanx so much more!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered in the first section of the github repository